# error C2653: 'boost' : is not a class or namespace name VC++ 2008 express

Tags: visual-c++, boost-python

I try to build simple hello world with boost python and 
visual c++ 2008 express.

I included path `E:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_47\` inside

`|Tools|Options|VC++ Directories|`  for Include files (and tried to put same path to all other),

but i still get error

`'boost' : is not a class or namespace name`

source code is:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace boost::python;

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
  try {
    Py_Initialize();

    object main_module((
      handle<>(borrowed(PyImport_AddModule("__main__")))));

    object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

    handle<> ignored(( PyRun_String( "print \"Hello, World\"",
                                     Py_file_input,
                                     main_namespace.ptr(),
                                     main_namespace.ptr() ) ));
  } catch( error_already_set ) {
    PyErr_Print();
  }
}
```

Comment: Try moving `#include <boost/python.hpp>` *after* `#include "stdafx.h"`.

Comment: Thank you, that solves it.Can you post it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to some oddities in how Microsoft's precompiled headers work, you always want the:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

...as the *firsts* line in any file where you use it. Any other header needs to come *after* that, so you want:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost/python.h>
```